Can Authors detach a syncd pattern?
As an admin I can create syncd patterns, and when I have added one I can "detach" it into its constituent blocks - so it essentially becomes unsyncd.
I thought other users could also detach my patterns, but it seems on my site that "Authors" cannot. Is that by design?
The only references I have found to "detaching" just describe how to do it, not any limitations.
